# Альтернатива метки (args...) для компилятора CL

Tags: c, макросы

Какая возможная альтернатива метки `args...` для компилятора CL? 
Например:

```
#define DECLARE_C_ARRAY(__type, __name, __page, __args...) \
enum { __name##_page_size = __page }; \
typedef __type __name##_element_t; \
typedef C_ARRAY_SIZE_TYPE __name##_count_t; \
typedef struct __name##_t {\
    volatile __name##_count_t count;\
    volatile __name##_count_t size;\
    __name##_element_t * e;\
    __args ;\
} __name##_t, *__name##_p;
```

пробовал вариант подавления запятой:

```
#define DECLARE_C_ARRAY(__type, __name, __page, ...) \
enum { __name##_page_size = __page }; \
typedef __type __name##_element_t; \
typedef C_ARRAY_SIZE_TYPE __name##_count_t; \
typedef struct __name##_t {\
    volatile __name##_count_t count;\
    volatile __name##_count_t size;\
    __name##_element_t * e;\
    ## __VA_ARGS__ ;\
} __name##_t, *__name##_p;
```

по прежнему получаю ошибку синтаксического разбора, типа (C2059)

Comment: Без примера использования Ваш код бесполезен.

Comment: в данной конструкции аргумент `__args` представляет собой элемент структуры. В отношении GCC, отсутствие аргумента не вызывает ошибку. Я подумал, может имеется аналог для CL, но ничего подходящего найти не могу. Можно, конечно, передать аргумент заглушку, типа `int x`, но хотелось все таки найти решение.

Comment: http://rextester.com/PXXSBG91440

Comment: Насколько корректно *до такой степени* сильно менять вопрос? это уже по сути совсем другой вопрос получается!

Comment: не совсем так, первый пример не отрожал суть проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Так ли уж необходимо делать это именно через `#define`?

По-моему, лучше через `vfprintf`, типа

```
void debug(const char * fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Нет?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убрать `args` и должно заработать в таком виде:

```
#define debug(format, ...) fprintf(stderr, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

<kbd>[Тест](http://rextester.com/EVDOTW13087)</kbd>:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define debug(format, ...) fprintf(stderr, format, __VA_ARGS__)

int main(void)
{
    debug("%s\n", "debug message");
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но это не то что мне нужно. необходимо подавить запятую, если args не используется. в спецификации GCC описан вариант использования `## __VA_ARGS__`, но компилятор CL не понимает это...

Comment: @ViteDecorum приведите в вопросе пример того, как Вы хотите использовать макрос для прояснения ситуации.

Comment: @ViteDecorum разве исключение имени перед троеточием и использование `__VA_ARGS__` в теле макроса не дают нужного результата? [Пример](http://rextester.com/DOWY51353).

Comment: мне нужно подавить запятую, если `args` не используется. см.: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: @ViteDecorum ещё раз Вас прошу: приведите пример использования. Я не понимаю, какую ситуацию Вам надо обработать. Вот [вариант](http://rextester.com/YEFX67095) и с запятыми и без, всё работает (нажмите `F8` для проверки).

Comment: вы правы, ситуация немного отличается от первого примера. помимо исключения запятой, необходимо исключить элемент структуры. на сколько я понимаю, ошибка с этим связана.